# Make Loading UIWebView faster by saving html page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making a `hybrid iOS app`. The native part of the app redirects to `UIWebView` that dynamic data. Is it possible to cache this data locally to make transition to the Webpage faster?

Comment: Do i simply save the html site?but doing that won't trigger the JS files

Comment: Its about 3 years ago since I did it, I can't remember the details. I'll have to see if the source code to that project is knocking around somewhere. It may have been using NSURLProtocol to perform interception. There were some issues with using the default cache options as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
NSData *urlData;
NSString *baseURLString =  @"mysite.com";
NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0]; 
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil]; 

if (connection)
{ 
   urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request];

   NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
   [htmlString release];
}

[connection release];
```